# Dropbox vs Android - Is it possible to set role with "openOrCreateDatastore"?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm looking for a solution to set role on my datastore with a ID that I have created. Indeed, on the [dropbox tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android#sharing-a-datastore) it is explained how to affect a role for a datastore with an ID automatically generated.

Someone could tell me if there is a solution to affect a role to a datastore with a name determined by the user of the app?

My code is :

```
title = extras.toLowerCase();
try {
    datastoreTitle = mDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore(title.toString());
    datastoreTitle.setRole(DbxPrincipal.PUBLIC, DbxDatastore.Role.EDITOR);  
} catch (DbxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run this code I get this error message :

```
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dvp_list7/com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticlesDropb}: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxRuntimeException$IllegalArgument: Operation setRole requires a shareable datastore.
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:155)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1252)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5096)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716): Caused by: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxRuntimeException$IllegalArgument: Operation setRole requires a shareable datastore.
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxDatastore.checkShareable(DbxDatastore.java:241)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxDatastore.setRole(DbxDatastore.java:314)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticlesDropb.dataManager(ListingArticlesDropb.java:165)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticlesDropb.onCreate(ListingArticlesDropb.java:92)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5153)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
10-31 09:11:44.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22716):    ... 11 more
```

Thank you for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, roles are only applicable to shareable datastores, and `openOrCreateDatastore` only returns private datastores. There's more information in the [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/android) under "Private or shareable datastores". To quote a bit of that:

> Datastores with private IDs are created using DbxDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore(id). Private IDs are meaningful to the developer of the app, such as "default" (for the default datastore) or "settings". The scope of private IDs is the current user-app pair.

versus

> Datastores with shareable IDs are created using DbxDatastoreManager.createDatastore() which allows them to be shared between users. Their IDs are auto-generated and are not only unique for the user-app pair, they're also unique across Dropbox.